# Where am I wrong fetching unordered list simple html dom

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, simple-html-dom

I am trying to fetch `<div class="single-event__code">`,`<div class="single-event__time">` & `<div class="single-event__players">` using below PHP codes, if i print data from `<div class="app_content">` all data that are inside that DIV will be printed out but if i change to one of those mentioned above no any data will be printed out i don't know where am i doing wrong i have tried many ways but problem persist, i tried with DOM Document same thing happen, need your advice this is driving me crazy.

```
 <div class="app_content">
 <ul class="js-events-container">
 ::BEFORE
<li class="single-event live">...</li>
<li class="single-event live">...</li>
<li class="single-event live">...</li>
<li class="single-event live">...</li>
<li class="single-event live">
 ::before
 //First DIV of li
<div class="single-event__code">
Event Code: <strong>96441</strong>
           </div>
    <div class="single-event__time">
        <span class="score js-score">LIVE</span>
        <span class="time js-timer"></span>
        </div>
    <div class="single-event__players">
   <a href="/sportsbook/SOCCER/BRAZIL_SERIE_D/400953/">
    AA Portuguesa RJ <span> v </span> Audax SP </a>
             </div>
   <div class="single-event__bets three markets">
<div class="single-event__bets__container js-bets-container">
            <div class="single-event__bets__price">
                 1.02
                  </div><div class="single-event__bets__price">
                 81.00
                  </div><div class="single-event__bets__price">
                 101.00
                  </div></div>
             <div class="single-event__bets__more">
   <a href="/sportsbook/SOCCER/BRAZIL_SERIE_D/400953/" data-markets="+18">+
  <span>+18</span></a></div>
    </div>
   ::after
   </li>

<li class="single-event live">...</li>
<li class="single-event live">...</li>
<li class="single-event live">...</li>
<li class="single-event live">...</li>

   ::AFTER </ul>
</div>
```

PHP CODES

```
 <strong>STAFF AT TOP</strong>
  <?php
  include('advanced_html_dom.php'); 

  $html = file_get_html('https://www.mkekabet.com/sportsbook/SOCCER/');
   $table = $html->find('.app__content', 0);
   $links = $table->find('.js-events-container', 0);
   $table2 = $links->find('.single-event live', 0);
    $links2 = $table2->find('.single-event__code', 0);

   echo $links2;
```

Comment: You're missing some `$`s.

Comment: That was just a typing error when i was writing a question here, the problem is still there. @pguardiario

Comment: You're also using find wrong: `find($css, 0)` -> return the first element.

Comment: If i change index number example on the first table and be like `$table = $html->find('.app__content', 0)` it is output content of that index number but if `echo` the `$links` it does not output anything even if i change the index number and the funny thing is if i want to output `$table2` and `$links2`  it is saying `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object` does that mean they are not recognized or i misunderstood, why it is reacting like this :-(

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you seem to have wrong selector in place.

```
table2 = $links->find('.single-event live');
```

is supposed to be

```
table2 = $links->find('.single-event.live');
```

As `single-event` and `live` are classes on the same element.

Comment: It is saying `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='` but if i try to print by modifying code like this `$html = file_get_html('https://www.mkekabet.com/sportsbook/SOCCER/');
   $table = $html->find('.app__content');
   $links = $table->find('.js-events-container');
  // table2 = $links->find('.single-event.live');
   //links2 = $table2->find('.single-event__code');

   echo $table;` it print the content that is inside that DIV @Sushanth

Comment: are you there bro? @Sushanth